# AS3: Possible to read ppt file?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, powerpoint

Is it possible to get the content of a ppt file with as3? Possibliy similar to loading and reading an xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, yes. You can load a PPT file to your SWF using a [`URLLoader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) whose `dataFormat` is set to `URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY` and write code to parse it based on the [PPT binary file format](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/officebinaryformats.mspx#EOB) released by Microsoft. In practice, I'd say that's not going to be an easy task.

Consider open sourcing your ActionScript API for parsing PPT once you're done with it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly no quick solution, like the XML and XMLList classes for XML, and so whilst it may be possible in theory if you write your own classes to read in the no-doubt far more complex PPT format, in practice it isn't.